# How update entity after adding new entity in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a two tables `Client` and `ClientSecret`. The tables have following structure:

```
public class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public List<ClientSecret> ClientSecrets { get; set; }
    }

public class ClientSecret
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Expiration { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

I need for of all create a new `Client` set the `ClientId` and `ClientName` and get back a new `Id` of this object from DB.

I have tried this (`_dbContext` is getting via DI system in the constructor):

```
var newClient = new Client();
newClient.ClientName = client.ClientName;
newClient.ClientId = client.ClientId;
_dbContext.Clients.Add(newClient);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

var newClientId = newClient.Id;
var clientToUpdate = await _dbContext.Clients.Where(x => x.Id == newClientId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

clientToUpdate.ClientSecrets.AddRange(secrets);
_dbContext.Clients.Update(clientToUpdate);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I need first create a `Client` because the table `ClientSecrets` needs a `ClientId` for creating a new records into this table.

I got this error message:

Failed the in the row with: `_dbContext.Clients.Update(clientToUpdate);`

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Client' cannot
>   be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is
>   already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a
>   unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if
>   the key property is assigned the default value for its type).  If you
>   are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not
>   collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other
>   new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You are using EF Core like when you write raw sql queries, which kind of beats many of the advantages of an ORM

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The instance of entity type 'Client' cannot be tracked because another
>   instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked

there is already an instance of `client` created on `_dbContext.Clients.Add(newClient);`.

you need to Detach the first entry before attaching your updated entry

after

```
_dbContext.Clients.Add(newClient);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

add code for detaching

```
_dbcontext.Entry(newClient).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Comment: Works perfectly, it was quick fix! :) Thank you Ashik irsha.

Comment: save my day, trhanks

Comment: why is deattachment not automatic?  what is gained by not deattaching after a savecommit.  The code worked.  I ran into this problem which unit testing with an add and commitsave then an update

Answer (score 9):

You are using EF Core like when you write raw SQL queries, which kind of beats many of the advantages of an ORM.

You don't need the `ClientId` for `ClientSecrets`, because EF Core can figure out the relations itself.

```
var newClient = new Client
{
    ClientName = client.ClientName,
    ClientId = client.ClientId,
    ClientSecrets = secrets.ToList() // or ToArray or whatever it is
};

_dbContext.Clients.Add(newClient);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

It's not a problem that ClientSecret requires a back reference to the `Client` class, by adding your secrets to the model, you establish a relationship of `ClientSecret` to `Client`.

When you save now, EF Core will know it has first to add the `Client` and then add the `ClientSecret`s

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kindly add the following it works for me 25th Friday, Sept 2020.
AsNoTracking solves it for me. as i was able to update mine. Thanks

```
var clientToUpdate = await _dbContext.AsNoTracking().Clients.Where(x => x.Id == newClientId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

clientToUpdate.ClientSecrets.AddRange(secrets);
_dbContext.Clients.Update(clientToUpdate);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```